# How to make Tooltip work with Quantity?

Tags: units, tooltip

When I execute the code below:

```
Tooltip[Quantity[1, "Month"], "how to make it works?"]
```

The tooltip that is automatically generated by `Quantity` prevails over the one I added myself with `Tooltip`.

[image: the tooltip is "unit: month" instead of the desired string]

I would like to preserve the `Quantity` objects (rather than convert them to strings), but I would like to be able to override the automated tooltip with my own.

How can I fix It?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Create a wrapper for adding a [`Tooltip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html) to a [`Quantity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html)

```
qTooltip[q_Quantity, tt_String] :=
 Tooltip[QuantityForm[q, "Abbreviation"], tt]
```

Like other wrappers (e.g., [`MatrixForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm.html)), the wrapper should not be included in variable definitions.

```
qTooltip[quant = Quantity[1, "Month"], "how to make it work?"]

(* Tooltip[1*"mo", "how to make it work?", 
   TooltipStyle -> "TextStyling"] *)
```

The definition of `quant` does not include the wrapper.

```
QuantityMagnitude[quant]

(* 1 *)

UnitConvert[quant, "days"]

(* Quantity[365/12, "Days"] *)
```

**EDIT:** You do not necessarily need to restrict the tooltip to being a string, and you can default to a normal `Tooltip` for none quantities.

```
Clear[qTooltip];

plt[n_?NumericQ] := Plot[x^n, {x, 0, 1}];

qTooltip[q_Quantity, tt_] :=
  Tooltip[QuantityForm[q, "Abbreviation"], tt];

qTooltip[q_, tt_] := Tooltip[q, tt];
```

Examples (outputs deleted):

```
qTooltip[quant = Quantity[1, "Month"], plt[1]]

qTooltip[n = 3, plt[n]]
```